# OpenCV: How to make the gray text darker?

Tags: opencv, tesseract, grayscale

I have a scanned document image where some texts are in light gray and some texts are in black colors.

I have tried using Dilation in OpenCV hoping to make the gray changed towards a black color (darker) but it just made the text font image thinner.

What will be the ideal way to make the light gray text darker without affecting the surrounding?  The scanned document image is black texts on white background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try doing binarizing the image .Then you can make your images to black and white.[opencv documentation for thresholding is here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). I'm doing character segmentation project for old newspaper images and otsu's binarization works for my scenario.